# Highcharts Accessible navigation without using arrow keys

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, accessibility, react-highcharts

Is there a way to allow users to navigate without needing to use the arrow keys, but instead just the tab key? In my use case, the entire page uses tab (no arrows) and when the user reaches the legend and presses tab, it skips the remaining legend items and exits the chart. (accessibility.keyboardNavigation.order is set to ["legend"], hence why it doesn't enter another part of the chart).

Is there any option to allow both/either tab **or** arrow keys to navigate within one section of the chart? I scoured the documentation but could not find this.

tldr I want user to be able to press tab key to navigate through all the legend items instead of having to switch to the arrow keys.

Comment: Adding array with elements to options order should help [accessibility.keyboardNavigation.order](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/accessibility.keyboardNavigation.order)

Comment: @SebastianHajdus thanks for the response. In the documentation it says "Available elements are: series, zoom, rangeSelector, chartMenu, legend and container." I have it set to ["legend"]. Could you elaborate what you were suggesting to add?

Comment: Do you want to navigate into one section example for legend by tab but items in the middle by arrows, something like this you want to achieve?

Comment: Inside you will find a workaround to your case [Github link](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6886#issuecomment-310667473)

Comment: It doesn't matter to me if arrow keys work or not; but I want the tab key to navigate between the items within the legend instead of navigating out of the legend. I tried enabling the option it outlines in that github link, but it's neither in the docs nor did it have any effect unfortunately.

Comment: Please show me a simplified version of your case for test.

Comment: It's just any highcharts chart with a legend. I don't see a way to test tab order in jsfiddle, but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/83vc69ut/)